# Mysql/PHP Querying a table value containing reserved words

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm doing some maintenance on a clients website that uses the simple mysql_query() function for all of their database queries. On one of their pages, a query is done to pull user information based on their nickname. The file is very robust and going through and changing every instance to pull from user IDs instead of nicknames is not really feasible.

They're running into problems with some nicknames, particularly "Link", "Echo", "Slayer". I see why link and echo could potentially cause issues with the query, but not so much Slayer. Is there anything I can do (aside from preventing creation of these names in the future) to help the query go through and pull the information I need?

Edit:
The whole function:

```
function userInfo($username){
    global $username_array;
    $username = prepare($username);
    $username_array = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '$username' LIMIT 1"));
}
```

It should return an array $username_array back to the original script. With 99% of users, this works fine. For some reason, the users above, this done not work.

```
function prepare($val,$type=0){
$val = XSS($val);
$val = sqlInjection($val);
return $val;
```

}

```
function XSS($val) {
   // remove all non-printable characters. CR(0a) and LF(0b) and TAB(9) are allowed
   $val = preg_replace('/([\x00-\x08][\x0b-\x0c][\x0e-\x20])/', '', $val);

   // straight replacements, the user should never need these since they're normal characters
   // this prevents like <IMG SRC=&#X40&#X61&#X76&#X61&#X73&#X63&#X72&#X69&#X70&#X74&#X3A&#X61&#X6C&#X65&#X72&#X74&#X28&#X27&#X58&#X53&#X53&#X27&#X29>
   $search = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
   $search .= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
   $search .= '1234567890!@#$%^&*()';
   $search .= '~`";:?+/={}[]-_|\'\\';
   for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($search); $i++) {
      // ;? matches the ;, which is optional
      // 0{0,7} matches any padded zeros, which are optional and go up to 8 chars
      // &#x0040 @ search for the hex values
      $val = preg_replace('/(&#[x|X]0{0,8}'.dechex(ord($search[$i])).';?)/i', $search[$i], $val); // with a ;
      // &#00064 @ 0{0,7} matches '0' zero to seven times
      $val = preg_replace('/(&#0{0,8}'.ord($search[$i]).';?)/', $search[$i], $val); // with a ;
   }

   // now the only remaining whitespace attacks are \t, \n, and \r
   $ra1 = Array('javascript', 'vbscript', 'expression', 'applet', 'blink', 'script', 'iframe', 'frameset', 'ilayer', 'bgsound');
   $ra2 = Array('onabort', 'onactivate', 'onafterprint', 'onafterupdate', 'onbeforeactivate', 'onbeforecopy', 'onbeforecut', 'onbeforedeactivate', 'onbeforeeditfocus', 'onbeforepaste', 'onbeforeprint', 'onbeforeunload', 'onbeforeupdate', 'onblur', 'onbounce', 'oncellchange', 'onchange', 'onclick', 'oncontextmenu', 'oncontrolselect', 'oncopy', 'oncut', 'ondataavailable', 'ondatasetchanged', 'ondatasetcomplete', 'ondblclick', 'ondeactivate', 'ondrag', 'ondragend', 'ondragenter', 'ondragleave', 'ondragover', 'ondragstart', 'ondrop', 'onerror', 'onerrorupdate', 'onfilterchange', 'onfinish', 'onfocus', 'onfocusin', 'onfocusout', 'onhelp', 'onkeydown', 'onkeypress', 'onkeyup', 'onlayoutcomplete', 'onload', 'onlosecapture', 'onmousedown', 'onmouseenter', 'onmouseleave', 'onmousemove', 'onmouseout', 'onmouseover', 'onmouseup', 'onmousewheel', 'onmove', 'onmoveend', 'onmovestart', 'onpaste', 'onpropertychange', 'onreadystatechange', 'onreset', 'onresize', 'onresizeend', 'onresizestart', 'onrowenter', 'onrowexit', 'onrowsdelete', 'onrowsinserted', 'onscroll', 'onselect', 'onselectionchange', 'onselectstart', 'onstart', 'onstop', 'onsubmit', 'onunload');
   $ra = array_merge($ra1, $ra2);

   $found = true; // keep replacing as long as the previous round replaced something
   while ($found == true) {
      $val_before = $val;
      for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ra); $i++) {
         $pattern = '/';
         for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($ra[$i]); $j++) {
            if ($j > 0) {
               $pattern .= '(';
               $pattern .= '(&#[x|X]0{0,8}([9][a][b]);?)?';
               $pattern .= '|(&#0{0,8}([9][10][13]);?)?';
               $pattern .= ')?';
            }
            $pattern .= $ra[$i][$j];
         }
         $pattern .= '/i';
         $replacement = substr($ra[$i], 0, 2).'<x>'.substr($ra[$i], 2); // add in <> to nerf the tag
         $val = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $val); // filter out the hex tags
         if ($val_before == $val) {
            // no replacements were made, so exit the loop
            $found = false;
         }
      }
   }
   return $val;
}

function sqlInjection($val){
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
    $val = stripslashes($val);
  }
  if(version_compare(phpversion(),"4.3.0") == "-1"){
    return mysql_escape_string($val);
  }else{
    return mysql_real_escape_string($val);
  }
}
```

Comment: There should never be a situation where a username being a reserved word can cause your query to fail, unless you're doing something *very* wrong.

Comment: The query: $username_array = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name`='$username' LIMIT 1")); When you echo the query string, it's SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name`='Slayer' LIMIT 1"

Comment: And what's the error you're getting for that query?

Comment: The problem is I'm not getting any errors at all. It's simply not returning anything. I've turned error_reporting to E_ALL and even tried or die(mysql_error()) and no errors are returned.

Comment: If you change that to `var_dump(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='Slayer' LIMIT 1"))`, what do you get? Also, *is there* any record in the database with the username "Slayer"?

Comment: or a person with code name slayer trying to break into your website? YOUR CODE IS OPEN TO SQL INJECTION.

Comment: When I use var_dump, I'm getting "resource(12) of type (mysql result)". I've run the generated query in phpmyadmin and it does pull a single result.

Comment: @Salman A We sterilize every single variable that goes into every query and that comes from every form. While it may not be as protected as using PDO, it certainly does the job well enough and is not a concern.

Comment: How about `var_dump($username_array)`?

Comment: var_dump($username_array): bool(false). Seems like that means it's not getting any results, but I can still do the query in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Eric, and there's no error? Are you sure you're connecting to the correct database? Can you try this exact code in isolation, in a separate file, with just the MySQL connect call, then this call, and see what happens?

Comment: Okay, I've got a little more information about the issue, now. If I take the query and replace the variable $username with the text "Slayer", it works. However, for some reason it does NOT like the variable, even though if we output the query string, it says the value should be Slayer. The query works fine by itself on another page. So, there's got to be something more going on here. I've included the entire function above.

Comment: Sorry to ask but the definition of `prepare` function would also help.

Comment: The code has already been tested with removing the prepare() function and just using mysql_real_escape_string(), but I've included the functions above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem since no user input should ever be directly executed.

Make sure you escape the strings properly and consider using prepared statements incase someone has a nasty suprise waiting such as [this](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Lol, I love that particular xkcd.  The site unfortunately doesn't use prepared statements, but does have a thorough string cleansing function that's used before any queries are executed.

Comment: @Eric, you should use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) if you're not using prepared statements. Any other cleansing is optional, but this is mandatory.

Comment: This is already part of the cleansing and has already been performed on the above $username variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using strings that are php reserved words is not the issue with your problem.
you can have strings that are reserved words `$test = 'function';` is valid.  The issue lies elsewhere.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php